# Crear un objeto, con los elementos distintos entre dos objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, find

Tengo este ejemplo:

```
const data1 = [
{ id: 1, name: "hola" },
{ id: 3, name: "hola" },
{ id: 6, name: "hola" },
{ id: 7, name: "hola" },
{ id: 8, name: "hola" },
```

];

```
const data2 = [
{ id: 2, name: "hola" },
{ id: 3, name: "hola" },
{ id: 5, name: "hola" },
{ id: 7, name: "hola" },
```

];

```
data2.map((e2) => {
let res = data1.find((e1) => e2.id !== e1.id);
if (res) console.log(res);});
```

al ejecutarlo no genera la lista de la diferencia entre los objetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "hola" },
  { id: 3, name: "hola" },
  { id: 6, name: "hola" },
  { id: 7, name: "hola" },
  { id: 8, name: "hola" },
]
  
const data2 = [
  { id: 2, name: "hola" },
  { id: 3, name: "hola" },
  { id: 5, name: "hola" },
  { id: 7, name: "hola" },
]

const res = 
data1
.filter(e => data2.findIndex(e2 => e2.id === e.id) === -1) //Obtenemos los elementos que están en data1 pero no en data2
.concat( //Concatenamos los dos arreglos
  data2.filter(e2 => data1.findIndex(e => e.id === e2.id) === -1) //Obtenemos los elementos que están en data2 pero no en data1
)

console.log(res)
```